# Deriving type from Generic classes

Tags: java, generics, factory, type-safety

I have a generic class which takes two type parameters:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T, S> {
    private List<T> myList;
    private List<S> mySecondList;

    //...

    public void addToFirstList(T e) {
        myList.add(e);
    }

    //...
}
```

I want to be able to specify concrete types for these two parameters upon creating an instance of the class within a factory and then to be able to derive these types from within the rest of my code.

For instance, if I have the code:

```
public class AccessFactory {        
    public static MyGenericClass<Integer, Float> getInst() {
        return new MyGenericClass<Integer, Float>();;
    }
}

public class UsingFactoryClass {
    private MyGenericClass access;

    ...

    public foo() {
        access = AccessFactory.getInst();
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to derive that the `MyGenericClass` instance `access` in the `UsingFactoryClass` class uses the parameters `Integer` and `Float`.

Is it possible to do this without having to contend with type safety warnings everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare it as:

```
private MyGenericClass<Integer, Float> access;
```

Comment: +1.  The OP has to repeat the type parameters everywhere; that's just a fact of life.

Comment: +1. Thank you.

Ideally I'd like to be able to use the factory to create an instance and have the client be oblivious to the types used. Would I be right that in order to support that I'd have to bind the type parameters against an interface common to all implementations?

Comment: You could always declare it as `private MyGenericClass<?, ?> access;` if your `UsingFactoryClass` class truly doesn't care about the types. The key is you have to declare it with types of some sort to avoid the warnings.